# How to use Javascript to popup a new window with NEARLY the same html as its parent window

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I want to create multiple versions of print-friendly pages from a single page. I am considering to do it in this way: placing several buttons on the original page and, clicking one button will popup a new window with the same html as its parent window, but with some modifications (e.g., set display attribute of some DIV's to none).

It is possible to use javascript to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass an additional parameter to the current page's url and open it in a new window, like this:

```
window.open(document.location.href + "?print=true");
```

You can then read the URL parameter in JavaScript and do the necessary hiding and CSS alterations to make the document print friendly.

Speaking of which: Why not use a print-only CSS that does this for you? Then all you need to do in your code is:

window.print();

And in your document HEAD:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcssfile.css" media="print" />
```

And the CSS will make sure the page looks the way you want to in print. See [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) for more about printing in CSS.

Comment: Thx Prutswonder! Because I need to generate several different editions (say, one page with DIV A hidden, while another page with DIV B hidden) of print-friendly pages from the same non-print-friendly page, I cannot simply attached a css file with media="print" to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to setup javascript code to to this, something like:

```
window.open('myPage.html')

getElementById('<someid>').style.display = none
```

However, you may want to look into CSS print stylesheets, which allow to use CSS to specify the div hidings and whatnot. It has the advantage of not forcing the user to open a pop-up window and not taking the second page-load hit on your server. I found [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) to be a good place to get started.

Basically, to add a print stylesheet you setup a link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="myPrintStyles.css"/>
```