# How to open current page in a new tab with print stylesheet only?

Tags: css, printing

I have a separate stylesheet for print. I want to create a button that opens up the current page with only that stylesheet implemented and ignoring the rest. If it helps we are doing this in AngularJS.

This is to link the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/printer-friendly.css"  media="print">
```

I tried changing the default CSS for this page by:

```
<script>  
function changeStyle( themeName ){
document.getElementById( "basestyle" ).href= themeName+ ".css";
}
</script
```

The problem is that rest of the stylesheets are interfering.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531286/how-to-use-javascript-to-popup-a-new-window-with-nearly-the-same-html-as-its-par

Answer (score 0):

Create a version of that same page using the new style sheet only and link to it using `target='_new'`

```
<a target='_new' href='version_of_page_using_that_sheet_only'>print</a>
```

Comment: I thought of this but we have multiple CSS in our index which are loaded in one go. Even if I create a page with print stylesheet, it would still have loaded other stylesheets. So how do I force new version to utilize one specific stylesheet and ignore others ?

Comment: Is this page using partials or a master page, if so you probably want to break up the styling being used in the master page and move want you don't want for this page to another file that is not not include ?